# Using bitwise operators, find a logical not equivalent

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

Using *only*:

```
<< >> | ^ & +
```

How can I make a function that is equivalent to the logical not operator (`!`)?

Right now I have:

```
int i = (~x + 1) >> 31; 
int j = (x + 1) >> 31; 
i = i | j; 
i = i & 1; 
return i ^ 1;
```

It works for everything, but `-1`.

Comment: Your solution uses ~. Are we allowed to use that or not? Also, is x an integer or boolean?

Comment: your question states ONLY using these operators "<< >> | ^ & + 
" but then you try and use '~'   ?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you are working with `int`s that are 32-bit, signed, and use 2's complement notation.  The unique thing about the number 0 is that neither 0 nor its negation have a 1 for the sign bits.  This code would work if you were allowed to use the negation operator (-):

```
int not(int x)
{
    return (-x | x) >> 31 & 1 ^ 1;
}
```

You can't use minus, but that is ok because for all x we know that `-x` is equal to `~x + 1` which is equal to `(x ^ -1) + 1`.  That's how 2's complement notation works.  So the final answer is:

```
int not(int x)
{
    return ( (x^-1)+1 | x ) >> 31 & 1 ^ 1;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, here is the "ANSI" version of the function that makes no assumption about the size of the int and does not rely on the undefined behavior of right-shifting a signed int.  It works for me in MinGW:

```
int not(int x)
{
    unsigned int y = x;
    return (( ((y^-1)+1) | y ) >> (sizeof(x)*8-1)) ^ 1;
}
```

Comment: Right shift of signed integers is not recommended (implementation-defined according to the C standard).

Comment: Yes, sorry, my function was failing because of that.  I will edit it now to add an '& 1' to trim off everything except the LSB after shifting right.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding my code, read this: http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm

Comment: Omri: Is (-1 >> 16) entirely undefined, or just the upper 16 bits?

Comment: The results of bitwise operations on signed integers is also implementation-defined. It makes me think that the question must be valid only for unsigned values (in which case -1 is not a valid input), or that the answer depends on the behaviour of the compiler.

Comment: according to the C standard (at least C89, I will check C99 in a second), "Each implementation shall document its behavior in each of the areas listed in this section." So I can't really say what the result would be.

Comment: You are using quite a few more operators than the question allows (multiplication, subtraction, sizeof). But I'm not sure it's possible to solve the question as it is presented (i.e. without at least some assumptions about integer representation etc.)

Comment: You're assuming that a byte consists of 8 bits, which is a bit optimistic. `CHAR_BITS` from limits.h solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that x is a 32-bit unsigned value:

```
x = x | (x >> 1)
x = x | (x >> 2)
x = x | (x >> 4)
x = x | (x >> 8)
x = x | (x >> 16)
```

At this point, if x was 0 then it's still 0. If it had a non-zero value, it now has the bit pattern 111....111.

With a two-complement representation, you can now simply add 1 and get the desired result:

```
x = x + 1
```

This solution assumes quite a bit about integer representation, types, etc.

(The "code" above is not valid C code, of course).

Comment: @quasiverse - Then do `unsigned x = *(unsigned *)&arg;`, use `x for your computation, then do `arg = (desired_type)x;`

Comment: With signed integers, right shift has implementation-dependent behaviour.

Comment: Omri, you are incorrect asserting that x will have the bit pattern 111111...111111 after your code runs.  The right-shift operator does not operate in a circle.  Consider if x is 1.  None of your operations in your first block of code will change it to a value other than 1.

Comment: @David of course you're right. That'll teach me not to answer questions at 2:30am...

Comment: @David just a thought - it would still work if I took only the LSB as the answer. But it shows how unwise it is to program when you're tired.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of 'cheating', but:

```
bool logicalNot(int i)
{
    return((bool)i ^ true);
}
```

I'm assuming there's nothing in the rules about composition of functions/typecasting/implicit type conversions?

Comment: The C language does not have a `bool` type; the best you can get is `typedef unsigned char bool`, which will not work for this purpose.